# phpmyadmin - How to add a prefix in columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a Database named "mediaCMS" and "posts" table, with following columns:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v08cS.png)

Some of numbers if you notice got (+) and some are only 8 numbers.

I just want to add (+) as prefix in all numbers that start with (965) so it going to be (+965).

So I just wonder how to change them in bulk?

Thank you,
regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am consider that you have some column has + value.

```
update tableName set number=concat('+',number) where number not like "%+%" and number like '965%'
```

Comment: excuse my question, but it shown me error: https://gyazo.com/c6c1466191f8aa4d13e118484d7846f9

Comment: you have write database name you should write databaseName.tableName

Comment: or write posts only

Comment: Ok, now it mess up all the numbers!, I just was want the numbers that starts with (965). now it change all numbers! https://gyazo.com/e1919c3cc11997298a26c316daa2e2a0

Comment: How to fix that now?, all numbers are with +! which its not correct. i just want the numbers starts with (965) to be (+965).. :( now everything changed.

Comment: update tableName set number=replace(number,'+','') where number not like "965%"

Comment: check it now  now